# NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/api/gax/grpc/GrpcStatusCode

Tags: java, spring, maven, google-cloud-platform

Developing `maven` spring boot application with Google Cloud Platform services including BigQuery, PubSub and Dataflow/Beam in the same application.

I added following dependencies through maven:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-pubsub</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
        <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-cloud-bigquery</artifactId>
        <version>0.33.0-beta</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
        <artifactId>beam-runners-google-cloud-dataflow-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

The problem is when the application is run, following exception is thrown:

> Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'pubSubAdmin' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/gcp/pubsub/autoconfig/GcpPubSubAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'pubSubAdmin' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'topicAdminClient' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/gcp/pubsub/autoconfig/GcpPubSubAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.TopicAdminClient]: Factory method 'topicAdminClient' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/api/gax/grpc/GrpcStatusCode

## My POM file content

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.RC1</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-pubsub</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
        <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-cloud-bigquery</artifactId>
        <version>0.33.0-beta</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
        <artifactId>beam-runners-google-cloud-dataflow-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
        <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.M2</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

With changes suggested by `João André Martins` another exception came up:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to construct instance from factory method DataflowRunner#fromOptions(interface org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptions)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.InstanceBuilder.buildFromMethod(InstanceBuilder.java:233)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.InstanceBuilder.build(InstanceBuilder.java:162)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.PipelineRunner.fromOptions(PipelineRunner.java:52)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.create(Pipeline.java:142)

Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.InstanceBuilder.buildFromMethod(InstanceBuilder.java:222)
... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/api/services/cloudresourcemanager/CloudResourceManager$Builder
at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.options.GcpOptions$GcpTempLocationFactory.newCloudResourceManagerClient(GcpOptions.java:369)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.options.GcpOptions$GcpTempLocationFactory.create(GcpOptions.java:240)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.options.GcpOptions$GcpTempLocationFactory.create(GcpOptions.java:228)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.ProxyInvocationHandler.returnDefaultHelper(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:592)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.ProxyInvocationHandler.getDefault(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:533)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:156)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy86.getGcpTempLocation(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowRunner.fromOptions(DataflowRunner.java:223)
... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.api.services.cloudresourcemanager.CloudResourceManager$Builder
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 17 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to make a similar project compile using your pom.xml, spring-cloud-gcp version 1.0.0.M2 and the following changes to your dependencies.

Hope this helps!

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
        <artifactId>grpc-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
        <artifactId>grpc-netty</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
        <artifactId>beam-runners-google-cloud-dataflow-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
                <artifactId>grpc-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
                <artifactId>grpc-netty</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: With additional dependencies you provided, i still get this: `Failed to read artifact descriptor for io.netty:netty-codec-http2:jar:4.1.20.Final Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.5`

Comment: It could be useful to send your whole pom.xml file. Using the dependencies I mentioned, along with the remaining ones you mentioned, using our BOM, worked for me.

Comment: i have include your suggestions and got a different exception `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/api/services/cloudresourcemanager/CloudResourceManager$Builder`. Please check updated post

Comment: Using your `pom.xml` with the changes I recommended, I'm able to do `mvn clean spring-boot:run` without seeing that issue.
I'd recommend running `mvn clean` on your project and if that doesn't resolve the issue, possibly also clear your local Maven repo (e.g., delete `~/.m2`).

Comment: `mvn clean spring-boot:run` produces same error, also deleted local Maven repo and redownload the projects repo still produced same error

Comment: A workaround was suggested in https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gcp/issues/442. Let's follow up there.